# Unlock a Level After Sharing on Facebook/Twitter

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, twitter, sharekit

I am creating an iPhone game with multiple levels, and I want one of the levels to be unlocked after the person playing it connects to Facebook or Twitter and shares the app. Is there a way to set this up relatively easily? I was also considering having a level that the person unlocks after liking a certain page or reviewing the app.

My current thought process is to create a sqlite database with a field that represents whether or not the level is unlocked. After the user connects to Facebook and posts something, the field changes so that the level is actually unlocked in the app.

Could you please guide me in the right direction with the appropriate API/starting sample code? Thank you so much. It'd be great if there was an example app somewhere demonstrating how this method works.

Answer (score 0):

> I want one of the levels to be unlocked after the person playing it connects to Facebook or Twitter and shares the app.

It think this would be a violation of [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/),

> IV. Application Integration Points
>
> 1. You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.